# DRF - routing additional HTTP methods for extra actions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement [routing additional HTTP methods for extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#routing-additional-http-methods-for-extra-actions) using django rest framework but am getting an error at `runserver`

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mapping'
```

Can't figure out what the issue is - Django 2.1.2, Python 3.6.5

```
class CustomerAPIViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                         mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                         viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, CustomerAdminPermissions)
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True)
    def order_guide(self, request, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = CustomerDetailSerializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @order_guide.mapping.put
    def order_create(self, request, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = CustomerDetailSerializer(instance, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@action.mapping` for routing additional HTTP methods was introduced in Django Rest Framework version 3.9.0. Earlier versions with raise an `AttributeError`. Try upgrading your version of DRF.

```
pip install djangorestframework --upgrade
```